# What is meant by "meaning systems" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I read a sentence in an [article in The Hindu](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.thehindu.com/opinion/lead/state-breaking-is-not-nation-making/article29214610.ece/amp/&ved=2ahUKEwiHrY6X0JrkAhXHuo8KHbD6CzMQFjAAegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw0bED_fQ_r79O8A6SMbqaaj&ampcf=1) which was:

> Certainly some people identify strongly with their community, others identify weakly, and still others move on and adopt the meaning systems of another community.

I don't know what "meaning systems" mean here. Any guesses? And I don't think it is anyhow related to premises it follows and those which follow it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an exact duplicate of the [same question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/222113/what-is-meant-by-meaning-systems-in-this-sentence) at ELL that already has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term "meaning system" refers to a manner in which a person or organization attributes meaning, along with the sources of held meanings (e.g., that person or organization's community) and how they interconnect.

https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/17439760600566008?journalCode=rpos20